# Very long run times for drake, compared to when I run simply through R

Tags: drake-r-package

I am trying to use drake for my workflow. It seems to have a lot of potential, but I noticed that that drake takes a very long time to run, and even simple step that take less than a second when I run "manually", can take 20 seconds or more when they are run with drake.

I'm aware that I did not provide enough details on this problem. Please tell me what kind of details to provide, and I will do so.

The dataset contains protein levels (a few tens) measured in patients undergoing various treatments. The protein levels are read from an ExpressionSet object, and then a linear model (including contrasts) is performed on each of these proteins. Here are the essential parts of the code:

```
pt_df_for_lm <- function(protein, eset){
  as.data.frame(exprs(eset)[protein,]) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "Sample.Name") %>%
  magrittr::set_colnames(c("Sample.Name","pt_level")) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  inner_join(pData(eset), by = "Sample.Name") %>% 
  mutate(drug.visit = ifelse(visit_id=="W0", "W0", paste0(drug.dose, ".", visit_id))) %>% 
  mutate(drug.visit = fct_relevel(factor(drug.visit), "W0") ) %>% 
  select(Sample.Name, drug.dose, patient_id, visit_id, drug.visit, pt_level) %>% 
  return()
}


lm_contrasts_drug_vs_placebo <- function(res_lm){

  coef_names <- names(coef(res_lm))

  contrasts_mat <-
    tibble(coef = coef_names) %>% 
    filter(!grepl("patient_id",coef)) %>% 
    mutate(term=make.names(sub("drug.visit","",coef))) %>% 
    inner_join(possible_terms_df) %>% 
    filter(drug!="Placebo") %>% 
    mutate(contrast_name = paste0(make.names(drg.ds),".",week, " - Placebo.0.", week)) %>% 
    mutate(coef_placebo = paste0("drug.visitPlacebo.0.",week)) %>% 
    mutate(contrast_vector = map2(coef, coef_placebo, function(cf_drug, cf_placebo){
      contrast_vector <- rep(0,length(coef_names))
      contrast_vector[which(coef_names==cf_drug)] <- 1
      contrast_vector[which(coef_names==cf_placebo)] <- -1
      return(contrast_vector)
    } )) %>% 
    transmute(contrast_tbl = map2(contrast_name, contrast_vector, function(cname, cvec){
      ctbl <- enframe(cvec, name = NULL)
      names(ctbl) <- cname
      return(ctbl)
    } )) %>% 
    deframe() %>% 
    bind_cols() %>% 
    as.matrix() %>% 
    magrittr::set_rownames(coef_names) %>% 
    t()

  contrast_results_df <-
    multcomp::glht(model=res_lm, linfct = contrasts_mat ) %>% 
    summary() %>% 
    broom::tidy() %>% 
    dplyr::select(-rhs) %>% 
    rename(term = lhs)

  possible_terms_df %>% 
    inner_join(contrast_results_df) %>% 
    return()
}


plan <- drake_plan(
  pt_eset = target(readRDS(paste0(INDIR,"pt_results.rds"))),
  pt_df = target(pt_df_for_lm(prot, pt_eset),
                 transform=map(prot=!!all_proteins)),
  res_pt_lm = target(lm(pt_level ~0 + patient_id + drug.visit, data = pt_df),
                  transform=map(prot, .id=prot)),
  res_pt_lm_df = target(res_pt_lm %>% 
                       broom::tidy() %>% 
                       filter(!grepl("patient_id",term)) %>% 
                       mutate(term = make.names(sub("drug.visit","",term))) %>% 
                       mutate(protein = prot) %>% 
                       select(protein, everything()),
                     transform=map(res_pt_lm, prot, .id=prot)),
  res_pt_lm_contrasts_df = target(lm_contrasts_drug_vs_placebo(res_pt_lm) %>% 
                                    mutate(protein=prot),
                                  transform=map(res_pt_lm, prot, .id=prot)),
  combined_res_pt_lm_df = target(bind_rows(res_pt_lm_df, res_pt_lm_contrasts_df),
                                 transform=combine(res_pt_lm_df, res_pt_lm_contrasts_df)),
  output_res_pt_lm_df = write_csv(combined_res_pt_lm_df,
                                  file_out(!!file.path(OUTDIR,"pt_lm_results.csv"))),
  trace = TRUE
  )

config <- drake_config(plan)
#vis_drake_graph(config)
make(plan, lock_envir=FALSE)
```

The code is placed within an rmarkdown notebook.

Gil

Comment: You could start with providing your code, because for all we know you may be using it wrong. Second is drake provides a lot of features, but everything has a cost. It all depends on which exactly features you use, but just try to imagine it. It analizes your code for optimization opportunities, it ain't easy. It can skip calculation steps if they were done before after you change code. That means it stores results of every step somehow. It's expensive on the first run, but makes successive runs faster. But what if you change input data? Well then all previously stored results are void. Etc.

Comment: I will add a code to the original post

Comment: Seeing the code does help. Would it be possible to post something I can run? Currently, I cannot create the plan because the `all_protens` object is not defined, and I cannot run the plan because I do not have the `pt_results.rds` file. If these are things you cannot share, we can try to work around it.

Comment: It would also help to know roughly how many targets are in the plan, and even more importantly, what is the size of the data. `drake` stores every target you build, and storage is a common bottleneck. I suspect your data is large and your computation is fairly small, so you may want to split up your workflow into a smaller number of targets.

Comment: If you cannot reduce the size of your data or reduce the number of targets, you could alternatively select a faster storage format. "fst" format in particular offers a large speedup for data frames: https://github.com/ropensci/drake/pull/977.

Comment: Thank you. I will try the "fst" format.I will also work on a reproducible example, because I can't share the dataset I working on, but this will take a few more days.
From looking at `top`, I see that memory usage goes up. This is probably the problem.